# CDF of product of three independent random variables

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are three Rayleigh distributed independent random variables. I need to calculate the product CDF of the variables, i.e. $F_\lambda(x)=\text{?}$ where,  $\lambda  = XYZ$.

I am trying to solve the problem as follows.

\begin{align}
F_\lambda(p) & = \Pr(\lambda < p) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(XYZ < p) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X < \frac{p}{YZ}) \\[8pt]
& = 1 - \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-p/(YZ\delta_1)} \frac 1 {\delta_1} f_{1/Y}(a) f_{1/Z}(b) \, da\,db
\end{align}

I didn't go further as I think the way I am solving might not be correct.

Could you please help? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes knowing the answer will help one figure out how to get there.  (But sometimes not.)  Using *Mathematica* if the three independent Rayleigh distributions all have the same parameter $\sigma$, then the cdf of $XYZ$ is $\frac{8 \sigma ^6-p^2 G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{p^2}{8 \sigma ^6}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{8 \sigma ^6}$ where $G$ is the Meijer G function.

Comment: You might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55684/pdf-of-product-of-variables.

Comment: Hi! The solution should help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share a little detail about how to get to this solution?

Comment: Here is the *Mathematica* code:  `dist = TransformedDistribution[x y z, {x \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[s], y \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[s], z \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[s]}]; CDF[dist, p]`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the density function for $U=XYZ$ can be expressed as $$f_U(u)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty f_X(\frac{u}{yz})\frac{f_Y(y)}{y} \frac{f_Z(z)}{z} dy dz$$ in terms of the density functions for $X,Y,Z$.

While cdf $F_U(u)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty F_X(\frac{u}{yz}) f_Y(y) f_Z(z)  dy dz$.

Comment: Thank you! Is this equation for the PDF of the product of X, Y, and Z? How about the CDF?

Comment: I edited result to include cdf.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you share a little detail about how did you get to this cdf equation? I will also be grateful if you can share any insight on how to find any closed form solution to this equation.

Comment: $P(U\le u)=\int\int P(X\le\frac{u}{yz}|(Y=y)\cap(Z=z))f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dydz$  assuming independence of $X,Y,Z$.  I have made no attempt at getting a closed form solution for these Rayleigh distributions.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: I will be grateful if you advise about one more thing. How the PDF equation updates when $U = \frac{{XY}}{Z}$? Is it like $\int_0^\infty  {\int_0^\infty  {{f_X}\left( {\frac{{uz}}{y}} \right)\frac{{{f_Y}\left( y \right)}}{y}} \frac{{{f_Z}\left( z \right)}}{z}} dydz$

Comment: It is clearer when you use cdf.  $\int\int F_X(\frac{uz}{y})f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dydz$  So pdf is $\int\int f_X(\frac{uz}{y})\frac{z}{y}f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dydz$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Sir! May I have your advice on the following question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217119/pdf-related-to-three-random-variables