# PDF related to three random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

The capacity of a Rayleigh flat-fading channel is presented as

$
\int_0^\infty  {{{\log }_2}\left( {1 + \gamma } \right)f\left( \gamma  \right)d\gamma }
$

where $\gamma$ is a random variable, and ${f\left( \gamma\right)}$ is the PDF of $\gamma$.

I am trying to figure out the closed form expression of the capacity when $\gamma$ involves three independent random variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that $\gamma  = a + \frac{{bx}}{{yz}} + \frac{{cx}}{y} + \frac{d}{z}$. Assume $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constants.

In my thinking, the possible capacity is

$\int_0^\infty  {\int_0^\infty  {\int_0^\infty  {{{\log }_2}\left( {1 + a + bu + cv + dw} \right){f_{\left( {\frac{x}{{yz}}} \right)}}\left( u \right){f_{\left( {\frac{x}{y}} \right)}}\left( v \right){f_{\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)}}\left( w \right)dudvdw} } } $

${f_{\left( x \right)}}\left( . \right)$ is the PDF of $x$. Could you please confirm whether the above presentation of the PDFs and integration intervals are correct or not? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look right.  You need to get the distributions for random variables u,v, and w.  Then you need the distribution for the weighted sum bu+cv+dw.  finally you need to use that in $f(\gamma)$.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Sir!